# Cannot Move Objects in Design Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I created a new activity and I am trying to simply add buttons and place them in different areas in the layout, but I cannot move them anywhere but along the top, middle, or bottom of the layout. Is there a locked parameters option?

Comment: Which is your parent Layout in that? Try to put RelativeLayout as parent Layout in your view xml file.

Comment: try to use RelativityLayout and in this layout info: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html and also : http://androidexample.com/Relative_Layout_Basics_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=73&aaid=97

Comment: @RonakJoshi thank you for the help! Such a simple fix!